# How many and what kind of batteries are needed for LEGO Powered Up?

Tags: trains, powered-up

I'm considering picking up one of the Powered Up train sets. What kind of batteries does the included Powered Up remote control system use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The current line of Powered Up components uses AAA batteries. The Powered Up team has indicated that both regular or rechargeable batteries should work fine.

You will need 10 AAA batteries to control one train with the included remote, or 6 if you are using a smart device as your remote. Here's the battery layout shown in the instructions:

[image: Powered Up battery layout]